# Update version number in property file using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am new in bash scripting and I need help with awk. So the thing is that I have a property file with version inside and I want to update it.

```
version=1.1.1.0
```

and  I use awk to do that

```
file="version.properties"

awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"' '/version=/{
    split($4,a,".");
    $4=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]"."a[4]+1
    }
;1' $file > newFile && mv newFile $file
```

but I am getting strange result version="1.1.1.0""...1

Could someone help me please with this.

Comment: `echo version=1.1.1.0 |awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{$NF++}1'
version=1.1.1.1`

Comment: @PS. I personally think that should be an answer, with appropriate explanation.  I would accept that answer if I were the OP :) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned in your comment you want to update the file in place.  You can do that in a one-liner with perl:

```
perl -pe '/^version=/ and s/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)/$1 . ($2+1)/e' -i version.properties
```

#### Explanation

`-e` is followed by a script to run.  With `-p` and `-i`, the effect is to run that script on each line, and modify the file in place if the script changes anything.

The script itself, broken down for explanation, is:

```
/^version=/ and              # Do the following on lines starting with `version=`
s/                           # Make a replacement on those lines
    (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)/  # Match x.y.z.w, and set $1 = `x.y.z.` and $2 = `w`
    $1 . ($2+1)/             # Replace x.y.z.w with a copy of $1, followed by w+1
    e                        # This tells Perl the replacement is Perl code rather
                             # than a text string.
```

#### Example run

```
$ cat foo.txt
version=1.1.1.2
$ perl -pe '/^version=/ and s/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)/$1 . ($2+1)/e' -i foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
version=1.1.1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way, but here's one fix.

#### Test case

I am assuming the input file has at least one line that is exactly `version=1.1.1.0`.

```
$ awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"' '/version=/{
>     split($4,a,".");
>     $4=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]"."a[4]+1
>     }
> ;1'    <<<'version=1.1.1.0'
```

Output:

```
version=1.1.1.0"""...1
```

The `"""` is because you are assigning to field 4 (`$4`).  When you do that, awk adds field separators (`OFS`) between fields 1 and 2, 2 and 3, and 3 and 4.  Three `OFS` => `"""`, in your example.

#### Minimal change

```
$ awk -F'["]' -v OFS='"' '/version=/{
    split($1,a,".");
    $1=a[1]"."a[2]"."a[3]"."a[4]+1; 
    print
}
'        <<<'version=1.1.1.0'
version=1.1.1.1
```

Two changes:

- Change `$4` to `$1`

  - Since the input field separator (`-F`) is `["]`, `$4` is whatever would be after the third `"` (if there were any in the input).  Therefore, `split($4, ...)` splits an empty field.  The contents of the line, before the first `"` (if any), are in `$1`.
- `print` at the end instead of `;1`

  - The `1` after the closing curly brace is the next condition, and there is no action specified.  The default action is to print the current line, as modified, so the `1` triggers printing.  Instead, just `print` within your action when you are done processing.  That way your action is self-contained.  (Of course, if you needed to do other processing, you might want to print later, after that processing.)

Comment: basically I need to update version in file so there are no any input parameters. That why I try to use awk to find and update version and than to write back to file

Comment: @user6329667 I added another answer that handles in-place editing more cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `=` as the delimiter, like this:

```
awk -F= -v v=1.0.1 '$1=="version"{printf "version=\"%s\"\n", v}' file.properties
```

Comment: thank you for advice but in this case I will need to update manually each time my script to set new version, but I need to automate this

Comment: You say you automatically want to increment the minor version?

Comment: yes basically I need open file change last number of version and save it that's it